# Amazon Neptune queries using Gremlin: How to solve error "Task timed out after 10.01 seconds"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I'm trying to query my Amazon Neptune Database from a Lambda function that uses Python as the programming language.

My query is

```
 g.V('1').out().toList()
```

After 10 seconds I get the error: "Task timed out after 10.01 seconds"

I tried to change the evaluationTimeout to a larger value, but it doesn't work

```
g.with_('evaluationTimeout',100000000000).V('1').out().toList()
```

Using the above query I still get the error "Task timed out after 10.01 seconds"

So how can I change it to have no timeout or a very large timeout?

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely not Neptune that is timing out but the Lambda function. When you create a new Lambda function the default timeout is 3 seconds. You should check to see what your Lambda timeout is set to and also verify what the Neptune cluster query timeout is set to. The `evaluationTimeout` can be used to reduce the timeout but cannot be used to set a timeout beyond that set by the administrator of the cluster.